# Kivy window not opening up when i hit run, getting Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Heres my py file called loginscreen.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class loginscreen(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):

        loginscreen().run()
```

here's my kivy file called loginscreen.kv:

```
ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager

        Screen:
            name: "screen1"

            MDLabel:
                text: "HOT"
                size_hint_y: .5
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 200
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                halign: 'center'

        Screen:
            name: "screen2"

            MDLabel:
                text: "COLD""
                size_hint_y: .5
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 200
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                halign: 'center'
```

And here's my terminal output:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /Users/loginscreen.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-07-19_146.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2020, 18:51:23) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] v0.104.1
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'2.1 INTEL-14.5.22'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 615'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.20'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can someone explain to me why i cant get the kivy window to open when i hit run? on my main.py file, the window opens just fine, but not this one. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write any code that would start the app. Write `loginscreen().run()` at the bottom of the file, not within the `on_start` method as nothing will ever call that (nor would it make sense to start one app within the `on_start` of another).

Comment: I did it your way FIRST, and here is the error when i did that:

/usr/bin/python3 /Users/loginscreen.py
  File "/Users/loginscreen.py", line 8
    loginscreen().run()
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: So fix that error, or if you can't work it out ask a new question about it. It seems pretty clear: you have failed to write an indented block where there should be one.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, My man, the answer is simple.
Focus on the 4th line of code. Python is all about indentation (Spaces)

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class loginscreen(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):

loginscreen().run()
```

You see, the error is that you put loginscreen().run() inside the loginscreen() class. Hence the interpreter couldn't read it. You need to put it outside the class.

A better way to write this code would be:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class loginscreen(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):

if __name__=="__main__":
    loginscreen().run()
```

Adding the main class removes clutters and clarifies code a lot.

There's another error in your kivy file:
Under screen 2 You have put an extra " after the MDLabel text.
Remove that to avoid any future error